# Android R8 fragments implements but actually matches extends

Tags: android, android-fragments, proguard, androidx, android-r8

Currently used version is: androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:**1.2.1**. When I try to build release version, proguard (R8) show warnings like:

```
R8: The rule `-neverclassinline public class ** implements androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` uses implements but actually matches extends.

R8: The rule `-keep public class ** implements androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
  public <init>();
}` uses implements but actually matches extends.
```

I didnt find any related issues on bug trackers. What maybe the reason, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [issue 148963981](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148963981), which is already marked as fixed for the (upcoming, as of the time of writing this answer) Fragment 1.2.2 release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Fragment 1.2.2 has been released and it seems to solve the issue: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.2